# Cannot find "Greeting" in scope

Tags: android, ios, kotlin-multiplatform

I've build a KMM project in Android Studio but the ios app seems to not see the classes from the shared module. Initially it worked perfectly but now that I modified some classes in the shared module, the error appears.

My project structure looks this way:[image: project structure]

As you can see there are some compilation errors in the Platform class but the android app is working fine. The error says "The feature "multi platform projects" is experimental and should be enabled explicitly".

The ios app looks like this:

[image: ios app]

Later Edit:

So apparently I found that I encounter this errors when I add this dependencies in shared.build.gradle in the common source set:

```
        val commonMain by getting {
            dependencies {
//                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-core:$ktorVersion")
//                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-okhttp:$ktorVersion")
//                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-json:$ktorVersion")
//                implementation("io.ktor:ktor-client-serialization-jvm:$ktorVersion")
            }
        }
```

I need these dependencies to make requests to my ktor server.

Update: So the problem was that I added some libraries in the common set and those libraries did not have multiplatform support.

Comment: What have you changed? What's the content of `Greeting.kt`? Does android app see it?

Comment: Possibly I have marked the "kotlin" directories from the shared module as source root and added a httpclient and function in Greeting.kt. " suspend fun getVaccines(): List<Vaccine> {
        return httpClient.get(endpointBase + Vaccine.path)
    }"

Comment: @Philip Yes, the android app works perfectly.

Comment: try finding out `shared.h` to see what headers were generated. it should be inside shared.framework

Comment: It seems I do not have such a directory shared.frameworks or any shared.h file. In the iOS app I have a directory Frameworks but is empty.

Comment: do you share the kotlin module with cocoapods? if yes, you should open ios project via `xcworkspace` instead of `xcodeproj`

Comment: Ok, I did not know that. Thank you for the advice. But it still shows the same error, that it can not see "Greeting" class from the shared module. And yes, I use cocoapods.

Comment: have you build the project after opening `xcworkspace`? you can see how your build went, open build reports (CMD+9), select latest build, scroll to top. you should find something like "run custom shell script '[CP-User]' Build shared", inside will be gradle output

Comment: Yes the project build was successfully. Now when I run the iosApp from Android Studio I get some build failed errors saying it could not find/download some dependencies from the common source set in build.gradle. It's weird because when I run the Android app it works fine, it can find those dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

I had created a new KMM default app and selected the cocoapods option. From Android Studio, I opened the iosApp.xcodeproj - this is why I got the error.

Instead, I had to open the iosApp.xcworkspace. By additionally running `cd iosApp && pod install` I was able to build and run the app from Xcode.

[image: open Xcode from Android Studio]

Answer (score 2):

You may have to `cd iosApp && pod install` the first time you build the iOS app.

Comment: Tried to do a pod install, still not working. Sure here is my repo https://github.com/dogoPaprika/VaccinationCertificateApp/tree/develop

Answer (score 1):

If the Xcode errors are just showing up in source, but you aren't actually trying to build it, you'll need to try an "build" the project. That will trigger Kotlin to run, which will generate the declaration for `Greeting` in the shared header, and swift can see that.

Essentially, when you change Kotlin, Xcode can't see those changes right away, so you'll get an error if you write the code.

I'm am assuming that "initially it worked perfectly" is accurate, in which case you probably just need to rerun the build. The part about `The feature "multi platform projects" is experimental and should be enabled explicitly` is a message I've seen, but I assumed was a warning. I don't think that needs to be enabled anywhere, unless maybe you have warnings configured to be treated as errors. I haven't set up a new project in a while, though, so maybe something gets set by copy/paste that I'm not aware of.

Comment: Tried to clean the project, rebuild it, but it's still not working. Also when I run the iOS app some dependencies from common source set can not be downloaded. On the other hand when I run the Android app, those dependencies can be found properly.

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was that I added some libraries in the common set and those libraries did not have multiplatform support. Should have paid more attention.

Comment: What alternate approach have you tried? 

In my case I'm using "sqldelight" and "kotlinx-datetime" along with a plugin "kotlin-parcelize"